# How to create a Google CDN for a GKE service

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-cdn

I've deployed a wordpress site on GKE (kubernetes) and I can access my Site from the internet like this mysite.test.com and works like a charm. Now I want to use Google CDN to accelerate access. I've tried using an Ingress resource but I would like to do it using a Load Balancing on the Networking tab on Google Console. What steps do I need to take?

Comment: Keep in mind that WordPress most probably won't follow the CloudCDN caching guidelines: https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/caching

Comment: From my research, as of now, `nginx-ingress` can't be used with CloudCDN. Nginx relies on a level 4 (TCP) load balancer, and not a level 7 (HTTP) load balancer, necessary to integrate with CloudCDN

Answer (score 13):

I just wrote a post about using the Google CDN with Kubernetes:

https://medium.com/@chees/code-cooking-kubernetes-e715728a578c

The important parts:

- Use a service with `--type=NodePort`
- Create an **ingress** for that service
- Use `--enable-cdn` on the created backend-service (you can do this from the command line or through the networking tab on console.cloud.google.com)