# Expose service on custom port via `https` on GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am new to Kubernetes (GKE to be specific), this is my third week, so bare with me.

I've been tasked to expose a `statefulset` via `https` like this:

```
- https://example.com/whateva -> service:8080 (+Google Cloud CDN)
- https://example.com:5001    -> service:9095
```

I have been trying for a week now. It was under the impression that this requirement was pretty straight forward? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Questions:

- I would like to use the `managedcertificate` from the google cloud
  but it seems that's not possible?
- Which `ingress` implementation is capable of achieving this while providing understandable documentation?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41857418/5525824

Comment: I need the service to be accessible on port 5001, via https

Comment: Using [managedCertificate](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs) will require you to use [GKE Ingress for HTTP(S) Load Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress) which works only on port `80`,`443`. `GKE Ingress` will support your use case (both `managedCertificate`   and `CloudCDN`) but you won't be able to change the incoming traffic ports at the `Ingress` level. Are your requirements mandatory? Can they be altered in any way?

Comment: Thanks for elaborating. I didn't want to believe that this is not possible out of the box. I guess I will be able to alter the requirements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ingress` creates an L7/HTTP/HTTPS load balancer which can only forward HTTPS on tcp port 443.  The only load balancer that will forward port 5001 is the [Network TCP/UDP type](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/choosing-load-balancer#summary-of-google-cloud-load-balancers).  The network load balancers will not terminate ssl/tls so a `managedcertificate` can not be used.  The tls connection is passed through to pods in your cluster where the certificate and key must be present to handle the tls connections.